# _kernel_vsyscall () in core files

Tags: c, linux, coredump

My program suddenly crashes and raises this error in core files.

To be exact:

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00c60410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#0  0x00c60410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00444df0 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00446701 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0047d3ab in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x004856c5 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00485b09 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Is this related to Linux or I am making a mistake in my code?

How to resolve this?

Comment: The way to read stack traces is the Top indicates where you are *now* and the Bottom indicates where you *were*. Read from the bottom up looking for methods you own or called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in `free()`, which is likely a function you call in your program, and a common place to make mistakes. You likely freed an invalid pointer (possibly via double-free?). The stack trace shows all those other functions because those were called below `free()`. This is common when calling library functions incorrectly, so you generally just keep an eye out for things that you recognize. As a rule of thumb, you'll want to start looking at the furthest thing down a stack trace that you recognize (i.e. is in your program), though if there are other memory corruptions further up the stack or in your program, looking there won't help too much.

**Edit for clarity:** "Down the stack" means "toward the top of the list," since as sixlettervariables points out, you want to find the most recent place you *were* that you recognize. I realize that my initial wording could be confusing.

Comment: +1, "start looking at the furthest thing down a stack trace that you recognize".

Comment: The fastest way to find a bug that manifests itself in a crash in `free`, `malloc`, etc. is usually to run the program under Valgrind or ASan.